# Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to rebuild an ios app, that previously had no issues (first rebuild in 6 months or so). Environment is OSX 10.13.5 with all the latest updates, Xcode 9.4.1, Ionic is 3.20.0. Local cordova, ionic and node modules have been updated.

These plugins:

cordova-plugin-device
cordova-plugin-file
cordova-plugin-file-transfer
cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

Configured for manual signing. Provisioning profiles have been regenerated, with new certs, downloaded and installed (numerous times).

I cannot make this error go away in either debug or release builds:

> Check dependencies Code Signing Error: No profile for team
>   ‘8SEBNER3XM’ matching ‘ABM 2018 Dev’ found: Xcode couldn’t find any
>   provisioning profiles matching ‘8SEBNER3XM/ABM 2018 Dev’. Install the
>   profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode’s dock item) or select
>   a different one in the General tab of the target editor. Code Signing
>   Error: Code signing is required for product type ‘Application’ in SDK
>   ‘iOS 11.4’
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed: Check dependencies (1 failure)
>   Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/kerickhowlett/Documents/PhoneProjects/ABM/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Cocktail
>   Pro.xcworkspace,-scheme,Cocktail
>   Pro,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,Cocktail
>   Pro.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/kerickhowlett/Documents/PhoneProjects/ABM/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/kerickhowlett/Documents/PhoneProjects/ABM/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Despite what the message says, there is what seems to be perfectly valid provisioning profiles in both Xcode project General tab, and Build Settings (ie 'ABM 2018 Dev'). They match the files in Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder. The team id is verified as correct. The profiles been regenerated / re-installed many times. Xcode thinks they are valid from within Xcode (does not complain). Running as ‘ionic cordova build ios’ seems to have a different opinion, and complains about the profiles. Similar error with --release added to the command. Based on trial and error, it is the PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER that seems to be the issue. I've tried a number of variations but always get the same error, which seems bogus. I have tried both profile names and UUID's.

What am I missing?

Comment: is automated signing an option for you?

Comment: That error isn't all that important, your cordova project still compiled just fine and can be opened with Xcode.  You can sign and submit from Xcode and shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: William, I tried previously with no luck. Retrying I get this error:

No profiles for 'com.dbs.abmcocktailpro' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.dbs.abmcocktailpro'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile.

A freshly generated/downloaded profile has this string in it:

<string>8SEBNER3XM.com.dbs.abmcocktailpro</string>

The profile in the apple developer account looks fine (to me). Thx.

Comment: BShaps, why such a big alarming error message then? I try running the app from within xcode and I do not get the current changes. It seems to be the previous version of the app.

Comment: please confirm if you have logged in to your developer account in Xcode and use a unique bundle identifier ( on the whole app store ).

Answer (score 41):

Try to check Signing settings in Build settings for your **project** and **target**. Be sure that code signing identity section has correct identities for Debug and Release.

[image: image description here]

Comment: Mine looked very similar to what you show. I had iPhone Development and iPhone Distribution, but changing those to match what you have made no difference. Thanks.

Comment: This helped me, my problem was my development team changed for some reason, I selected the correct one and everything worked well

Answer (score 32):

I am now able to successfully build. Not sure exactly which step "fixed" things, but this was the sequence:

- Tried automatic signing again. No go, so reverted to manual.
- After reverting, I had no Eligible Profiles, all were ineligible. Strange.
- I created a new certificate and profile, imported both. This too was "ineligible".
- Removed the iOS platform and re-added it. I had tried this previously without luck.
- After doing this, Xcode on its own defaulted to automatic signing. And this worked! Success!

While I am not sure exactly which parts were necessary, I think the previous certificates were the problem. I hate Xcode :(

Thanks for help.

Comment: So basically: Starts and Stops working without good reason. Just like here.

Comment: Turning off automatic signing and then turning it back on is what solved it for me.

Comment: So basically: We hate Xcode, and then more words.

Answer (score 22):

I opened XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts and clicked on Download certificate. That fixed my problem

Answer (score 14):

Requirements:

1. Unique name (across all Apple Apps)
2. Have to sign in while your phone is connected (mine had a large warning here)

Worked great without restart on Xcode 10

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 4):

You can get this issue if Apple update their terms. Simply log into your dev account and accept any updated terms and you should be good (you will need to goto Xcode -> project->signing and capabilities and **retry** the certificate check. This should get you going if terms are the issue.

Comment: This answer is good. Have in mind this answer first. In my case, membership has expired.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Xcode, Your project, Signing and Capabilities tab and choose the correct team and sign in with your apple id

[image: xcode]

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was that my Xcode session was disconnected. Few weeks ago, I had to renew my licence to Apple Developer Program, maybe this was the origin of the issue.

To sum up, I went to xCode -> Preferences -> Account -> Log in again

My certificates were then reloaded to my Xcode

Comment: What do you mean by "Log in again" how do you log out from your linked accounts?

Comment: On the new xCode (14), go to accounts, then on the left side "Apple IDs", select the account you want to log out and click on the "-" sign at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be hard to solve, but all I had to do was to go to Signing & Capabilities and Select team: 'None' and then select the correct team again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was plugging my iPhone and allowing it as a simulator destination. Doing so required my to register my iPhone in Apple Dev account and once that was done and I ran my project from Xcode on my iPhone everything fixed itself.

1. Connect your iPhone to your Mac
2. Xcode>Window>Devices & Simulators
3. Add new under Devices and make sure "show are run destination" is ticked
4. Build project and run it on your iPhone

Answer (score 0):

ionic cordova build ios —prod

Even with provisioning error you can still build the app

Then go Xcode —> Product —> Build For —> Profiling

Worked fine for me !!

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone: Settings / General / VPN & Device Management / choose your developer profile / click "trust this developer"

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you need check your Bundle Identifier. It'd be unique. If you have Bundle Identifier as 'example, etc.' you need to change that identifier. After try again. Most likely there is no problem with the certificate