# AppCenter does not change shared scheme configuration in Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-app-center

When building a flutter application on app center, scheme specific configuration are not taking effect.

error: No profile for team '...' matching '*AppName* Distribution' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '.../*AppName* Distribution'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode, click **Runner** file on top left corner. Then in **Signing & Capabilities** tab choose team, it should solve, if there will be error in status: "Failed to create provisioning profile", Connect the phone and then click the "try again" button there
[image]

Here more solutions: [Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387873/xcode-couldnt-find-any-provisioning-profiles-matching)